# Is there a code that allows me to get the result of the following sql query in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to execute the following sql query and store the result in a variable using linq, but I could not find a way to do it?

The query works very well on sql server, but when I try to do it with linq it does not give me the result I expect,

the query is as follows,

```sql
SELECT ('PN'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),LenderId)+RIGHT('00000000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),NextSecuenceId+1,0),(9)))
 FROM LenderSequences WHERE LenderId = '30' AND TypeDocumentId = '1'
```

this is the linq code that I have until now

```cs
from LenderSequences in db.LenderSequences
select new {
  Column1 = ("PN" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)LenderSequences.LenderId) + ("00000000" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)LenderSequences.NextSecuenceId + 1)).Substring(("00000000" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)LenderSequences.NextSecuenceId + 1)).Length-9,9))
}
```

This is the result that I hope you will return

```
PN30000000001
```

Comment: Why not just execute the same exact query from .NET? And what result are you getting now that doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: if it can be executed I do not know how to do it I'm trying it using linq

Comment: You didn't answer my second question. Please make sure you read the comment and fully address it so that people don't have to repeat themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to break this up into two separate pieces:

First get the next sequence ID from the database:

```
SELECT NextSecuenceId
FROM LenderSequences
WHERE LenderId = '30' AND TypeDocumentId = '1'
```

You can get this value from the database however you wish, either using ADO.NET to execute the SQL directly, or using an ORM like Entity Framework.

The next step is to format it:

```
// Would already have this value, or could also get it from the database
var lenderId = 3;

// This value would come from your database, as above
var nextSeqId = nextSecuenceId;

// Add the zero padding as necessary
// Assuming you want the total length to be 10 digits
var tmp = lenderId.ToString().PadRight(10 - nextSeqId.ToString().Length, '0');

// Combine all the values to create the required format
var formattedValue = $"PN{tmp}{nextSeqId}";
```

Comment: but a question if in the nextsecuenceId I have 1000 for example of value, I will eliminate the 0 on the left

Comment: @Frankenstainero Yeah, this code will handle that scenario.  Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wCxLhh

Comment: Thanks for the help